# C# - What's with this weird 0 at the end?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie.
I have a problem with C#, I don't know why program prints me a "0" at the end of the first row :( Plz halp.

```
namespace Tabliczka_mnożenia
{
class Program
{
    static void NumbersInRow(int x)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
        for (int i = x; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
    static void NumbersInColumn(int y)
    {
        for (int i = y; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 0;
        Console.Write(" ");
        NumbersInRow(x);
        NumbersInColumn(y);

    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljsLW.jpg

Comment: Your new line starts after the y prints once.

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: You're missing a `WriteLine` after the row and before the columns, so that's the first number written from `NumbersInColumn`

Answer (score 1):

The `0` is printed intentionally from the `NumbersInColumn` function. You have just forgotten to print a line break after the `NumbersInRow` function, like this:

```
static void NumbersInRow(int x)
{
    Console.Write(" ");
    for (int i = x; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(i);
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Better to just do `Console.WriteLine();` and you don't have to include an empty string.

Comment: Thank you :) <3

Answer (score 0):

0 is printed by `NumbersInColumn` method.
WriteLine methods writes 0(y=0) and moves cursor to a new line.

Comment: Yes I get it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case y starts with 0. You are then calling console.writeline() which writes whatever you want and then goes to the next line.

You should return a new line before starting to iterate through the rows.

Comment: I get it now, thank you :)